# GROUP BY except for one column with priority

Tags: sql-server

I’m quite new to SQL and have been learning it for just a few months. I’ve been working on a script to remove ”almost” duplicate entries from my database using GROUP BY. I got 13 different settings in my table and I’d like to GROUP BY setting 1-12 and keep the 13th column free from the GROUP BY clause. I’ve achieved this with the use of MIN() but I’d like to improve SQLs decision-making by prioritizing what to keep in Setting 13. The column can take the value of 1, 2 & 3. How do I i.e. tell SQL to choose setting 13 in prioritized order of 1,3,2?

See my example code below:

`SELECT [Manual].[Setting_1],[Manual].[Setting_2],[Manual].[Setting_3],[Manual].[Setting_4],[Manual].[Setting_5],[Manual].[Setting_6],[Manual].[Setting_7],[Manual].[Setting_8],[Manual].[Setting_9],[Manual].[Setting_10],[Manual].[Setting_11],[Manual].[Setting_12],MIN(Setting_13) AS Setting_13 INTO OtherManual FROM Manual GROUP BY [Manual].[Setting_1],[Manual].[Setting_2],[Manual].[Setting_3],[Manual].[Setting_4],[Manual].[Setting_5],[Manual].[Setting_6],[Manual].[Setting_7],[Manual].[Setting_8],[Manual].[Setting_9],[Manual].[Setting_10],[Manual].[Setting_11],[Manual].[Setting_12]`

To clarify: I do want MIN(Setting_13) AS Setting_13 not to be MIN but instead a prioritized list.

Edit: to provide a minimal reproducible example see following code:
`CREATE TABLE Manual ( ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Setting_1 INT, Setting_2 INT, Setting_3 INT, Setting_4 INT, Setting_5 INT, Setting_6 INT, Setting_7 INT, Setting_8 INT, Setting_9 INT, Setting_10 INT, Setting_11 INT, Setting_12 INT, Setting_13 INT, ); INSERT INTO Manual (ID,Setting_1,Setting_2,Setting_3,Setting_4,Setting_5,Setting_6,Setting_7,Setting_8,Setting_9,Setting_10,Setting_11,Setting_12,Setting_13) VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), (2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2), (3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3), (4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2), (5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3), (6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3);`

ID 1,2 & 3 is identical on Setting_1-12 but differs on Setting_13. I’d like to GROUP BY 1-12 and keep the entry with 1 in Setting_13. For ID 4-5 there’s no 1 in Setting_13 but then I’d like it to keep 3. So the desired result from the query is to show ID 1,5 & 6.

Thanks in advance,
Jimmy

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Edited the original post with a example of the table I’m woriing with ane desired outcome.

Comment: `group by` doesn't seem well suited to this, especially if you need to also bring the original `ID` value across. Have you considered using [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) with `partition by` instead? You can create custom orderings in its `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code which did the trick. But it also changed the numbers in the table which is not optimal but it can be mitigated.

`SELECT [Manual].[Setting_1],[Manual].[Setting_2],[Manual].[Setting_3],[Manual].[Setting_4],[Manual].[Setting_5],[Manual].[Setting_6],[Manual].[Setting_7],[Manual].[Setting_8],[Manual].[Setting_9],[Manual].[Setting_10],[Manual].[Setting_11],[Manual].[Setting_12],MAX(CASE WHEN [Setting_13] = 1 THEN 6 WHEN [Setting_13] = 3 THEN 5 WHEN [Setting_13] = 2 THEN 4 END) AS Setting_13 INTO Manual2 FROM Manual GROUP BY [Manual].[Setting_1],[Manual].[Setting_2],[Manual].[Setting_3],[Manual].[Setting_4],[Manual].[Setting_5],[Manual].[Setting_6],[Manual].[Setting_7],[Manual].[Setting_8],[Manual].[Setting_9],[Manual].[Setting_10],[Manual].[Setting_11],[Manual].[Setting_12] ;`